# How to properly use get_or_create in a django serializer and avoid 'already exists' error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following django models, serializer and viewset.

```py
class Article(AbstractBaseModel):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        Manufacturer,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    provider1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Provider,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse(

            "smt_management_app:article-detail", kwargs={"name": self.name}

        )
```

```py
class Manufacturer(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(

        primary_key=True, max_length=50, null=False, blank=False

    )


    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse(

            "smt_management_app:manufacturer-detail", kwargs={"name": self.name}

        )
```

```py
class Provider(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(

        primary_key=True, max_length=50, null=False, blank=False

    )


    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse("smt_management_app:provider-detail", kwargs={"name": self.name})
```

```py
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)

    provider1 = ProviderSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:

        model = Article

        fields = [

            "name",

            "manufacturer",

            "provider1",

        ]


    def create(self, validated_data):

        manufacturer_data = validated_data.pop("manufacturer", None)

        if manufacturer_data:

            manufacturer, _ = Manufacturer.objects.get_or_create(

                name=manufacturer_data["name"]

            )

            validated_data["manufacturer"] = manufacturer


        provider1_data = validated_data.pop("provider1", None)

        if provider1_data:

            provider1, _= Provider.objects.get_or_create(

                name=provider1_data["name"]

            )

            validated_data["provider1"] = provider1


        article = Article.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return article
```

```py
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    filter_backends = (

        django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,

        filters.SearchFilter,

        filters.OrderingFilter,

    )

    filterset_class = ArticleFilter

    ordering_fields = "__all__"
```

When posting a new article I encounter an unexpected behavior. The manufacturer and provider in the following example do both exist but only the provider causes an error.

POST body:

```py
{"name":"article1","manufacturer":{"name":"123"},"provider1":{"name":"abc"}}
```

ERROR body:

```py
{"provider1":{"name":["provider with this name already exists."]}}
```

Why does it happen if everything is exactly the same for Manufacturer and Provider ?

Comment: when you use primary_key=True,  it implies that this field will be the primary key and uniquely identifies each record in the table. by default, when you set primary_key=True, django also adds a unique constraint to the field.

Comment: I do want each provider to have a unique name. What I am trying to do in the create method of the serializer is to assign an existing provider with the same name or create it if necessary. Weirdly enough this works with the manufacturer.

Comment: It depends on the requirements, you have to handle them in the serializers.py file not in the views.

Comment: @Tanveer That is what I am trying to do, handling the assignment of the provider to the article in the ArticleSerializer.